# how to store an image to redis using java / spring

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I'm using redis and spring framework on my image upload server. I need to store the images to redis. I have found the following question but it was for python. 
[how to store an image into redis using python / PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225053/how-to-store-a-image-into-redis-using-python-pil)

I'm not sure if it's the best way but I would like to know how to do it in java (preferably using spring framework). I'm using spring-data-redis which uses jedis.

I would like to know if it is a good strategy to store images in redis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redis is binary safe so, in the case of Jedis, you can use BinaryJedis to store binary data just as any other kind of value that you store in Redis.

And no, I don't think storing images in Redis, and thus in-memory, is a good strategy. That would have to be a very special use-case.

Comment: Hi! Is cloud would be better for storing images?

Answer (score 2):

First of all Redis is not a good option for storing images. Redis is inmemory so it will taking not be a good step to put files such as images in-memory.

If you want to enter images then you can use it as follows

Below are the steps

1) make your maven pom.xml with following jars

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
           <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
               <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
               <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
               <version>2.4.1</version>
            </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

2) make your configuration xml as follows

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd

        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">



    <bean id="jeidsConnectionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory"
      p:host-name="localhost" p:port="6379" p:password="" />

     <bean id="redisTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate"
      p:connection-factory-ref="jeidsConnectionFactory" />

     <bean id="imageRepository" class="com.self.common.api.poc.ImageRepository">
      <property name="redisTemplate" ref="redisTemplate"/>
     </bean>

</beans>
```

3) Make your classes as follows

```
package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

public class RedisMainApp {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml");
  ImageRepository imageRepository = (ImageRepository) applicationContext.getBean("imageRepository");

  BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("files/img/TestImage.png"));
  BufferedImage newImg;
  String imagestr;
  imagestr = encodeToString(img, "png");
  Image image1 = new Image("1", imagestr);

  img = ImageIO.read(new File("files/img/TestImage2.png"));
  imagestr = encodeToString(img, "png");
  Image image2 = new Image("2", imagestr);

  imageRepository.put(image1);
  System.out.println(" Step 1 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());
  imageRepository.put(image2);
  System.out.println(" Step 2 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());
  imageRepository.delete(image1);
  System.out.println(" Step 3 output : " + imageRepository.getObjects());

 }

 /**
  * Decode string to image
  * @param imageString The string to decode
  * @return decoded image
  */
 public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString) {

     BufferedImage image = null;
     byte[] imageByte;
     try {
         BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
         imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
         ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
         image = ImageIO.read(bis);
         bis.close();
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return image;
 }

 /**
  * Encode image to string
  * @param image The image to encode
  * @param type jpeg, bmp, ...
  * @return encoded string
  */
 public static String encodeToString(BufferedImage image, String type) {
     String imageString = null;
     ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

     try {
         ImageIO.write(image, type, bos);
         byte[] imageBytes = bos.toByteArray();

         BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
         imageString = encoder.encode(imageBytes);

         bos.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return imageString;
 }
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

public class Image implements DomainObject {

 public static final String OBJECT_KEY = "IMAGE";

 public Image() {
 }

 public Image(String imageId, String imageAsStringBase64){
  this.imageId = imageId;
  this.imageAsStringBase64 = imageAsStringBase64;
 }
 private String imageId;
 private String imageAsStringBase64;

 public String getImageId() {
  return imageId;
 }

 public void setImageId(String imageId) {
  this.imageId = imageId;
 }

 public String getImageName() {
  return imageAsStringBase64;
 }

 public void setImageName(String imageAsStringBase64) {
  this.imageAsStringBase64 = imageAsStringBase64;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "User [id=" + imageAsStringBase64 + ", imageAsBase64String=" + imageAsStringBase64 + "]";
 }

 @Override
 public String getKey() {
  return getImageId();
 }

 @Override
 public String getObjectKey() {
  return OBJECT_KEY;
 }
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.io.Serializable;

public interface DomainObject extends Serializable {

 String getKey();

 String getObjectKey();
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.util.List;

import com.self.common.api.poc.DomainObject;

public interface Repository<V extends DomainObject> {

 void put(V obj);

 V get(V key);

 void delete(V key);

 List<V> getObjects();
}

package com.self.common.api.poc;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;

import com.self.common.api.poc.DomainObject;

public class ImageRepository implements Repository<Image>{

 @Autowired
 private RedisTemplate<String,Image> redisTemplate;

 public RedisTemplate<String,Image> getRedisTemplate() {
  return redisTemplate;
 }

 public void setRedisTemplate(RedisTemplate<String,Image> redisTemplate) {
  this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
 }

 @Override
 public void put(Image image) {
  redisTemplate.opsForHash()
    .put(image.getObjectKey(), image.getKey(), image);
 }

 @Override
 public void delete(Image key) {
  redisTemplate.opsForHash().delete(key.getObjectKey(), key.getKey());
 }

 @Override
 public Image get(Image key) {
  return (Image) redisTemplate.opsForHash().get(key.getObjectKey(),
    key.getKey());
 }

 @Override
 public List<Image> getObjects() {
  List<Image> users = new ArrayList<Image>();
  for (Object user : redisTemplate.opsForHash().values(Image.OBJECT_KEY) ){
   users.add((Image) user);
  }
  return users;
 }

}
```

For more reference on sprinf jedis you can see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/using-redis-with-spring.html

Sample Code is taken from http://javakart.blogspot.in/2012/12/spring-data-redis-hello-world-example.html

Comment: Hi! Should i use cloud instead and get my images by url?

Answer (score 1):

Convert image to base64 string and store it on redis as key value pair.
How to convert image to base64 string can be found here 
http://ben-bai.blogspot.in/2012/08/java-convert-image-to-base64-string-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Taking hint from @global-warrior's answer, this is what I did (requires Java 8):

```java
private String getEncodedString(byte[] bytes) {
    return new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes));
}

private byte[] getDecodedByteArray(String string) {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(string.getBytes());
}
```

And used spring data redis repository and entity for storing and retrieving:

```java
@RedisHash("image") @Data @AllArgsConstructor
public class RedisImageEntity {
    @Id String checksum;
    String image;
}

public interface RedisImageRepository extends CrudRepository<RedisImageEntity, String> {}
```

Finally, in Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ResponseEntity<ImageUploadDTO> uploadImage(MultipartFile image) {
    // ...
    redisImageRepository.save(
        new RedisImageEntity(checksum, getEncodedString(image.getBytes))
    );
    // ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
ResponseEntity<ImageResponseDTO> getImage(String checksum) {
    // ...
    prepareImage(getDecodedByteArray(
        redisImageRepository.findById(checksum).orElse(null)
    ));
    // ...
}
```